# approximate simple function given parameters with neural network in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

I need to create a neural network that approximates a function given its parameters. I give four parameters to my neural network (A, x0, phi, omega) and I want to obtain, as output,

> A sin(omega x + phi) + x0

(I need this net as a part of another network)
However, I am not able to train the network as I obtain a very poor convergence. Why is that?

I use a fully connected network with three layers. This is the code

```
    def get_batches(N_batches):
        A = tan( random.uniform(low=0.,high=2*pi,size=[N_batches,1]))
        x0 = random.randn(N_batches,1)*10
        omega = random.uniform(low=0.,high=10*pi, size=[N_batches,1])
        phi = random.uniform(low=0.,high=2*pi, size=[N_batches,1])  
        x = linspace(0,t_max, n_max)
        x = tile(x,N_batches).reshape(N_batches,n_max)
        return (A*sin(omega*x+phi) + x0, hstack([A,x0,phi,omega]) )

    N_batches = 80
    N_epochs = 50
    t_max = 5.0
    n_max = 100
    n_par = 4

    net_layers = []

    net_inp = Input(shape=(n_par,))
    net_layers.append(Dense(25, input_shape=(n_par,),  activation="relu"))
    net_layers.append(Dense(25,  activation="relu"))
    net_layers.append(Dense(25,  activation="relu"))
    net_layers.append(Dense(n_max, activation="linear"))

    net_l = net_inp
    for i in range(len(net_layers)):
        net_l = net_layers[i](net_l)
    net = Model(net_inp, net_l)
    net.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam") 

    costs = zeros(N_epochs)
    for i in range(N_epochs):
        y_true, y_in = get_batches(N_batches)
        costs[i]=net.train_on_batch(y_in,y_true)
```

Even if I train more, I don't get better results than this
picture (approximated function and real function plot for a test sample):

[image: plot1]

The plot of the cost function is quite strange:

[image: plot2]

What mistakes did I do? Thank you!

Comment: For each batch the parameters [A,x0,phi,omega] are random. I think the network will never learn this parameters. I suggest first fixing these parameters(this could be randomly generating the parameters once) and use them to generate random batches.

Comment: I want to do the opposite: the parameters (A, x0, phi, omega) are the input, the network must learn to reproduce the sine function given those parameters

Comment: For sequence generation you should probably use a recurrent architecture.